# Why does output changes after I perform cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have built a neural network for performing regression. However, if I'm performing cross-validation before making prediction, the output changes. Below are the graphs with and without cross validation.

**With Cross Validation**

[image]

**Without Cross Validation**

[image]

The code that I use for cross validation

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

epoch = 5000

n_cols = X_train.shape[1]

def baseline_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

    return model

estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=epoch, batch_size=16, verbose = 0)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
print("Results: %.10f (%.10f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
print("RMSE:", np.sqrt(abs(results.mean())))

print(results)
```

for prediction

```
epoch = 5000
n_cols = X_train.shape[1]

def modelling():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='tanh', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

    return model
model = modelling()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs= epoch, validation_split = 0.3, batch_size= 16, verbose = 0)
```

Using keras with tensorflow backend

Comment: Why exactly should two models with different input layers (in no. of nodes and activation function) produce the same results?

Answer (score 1):

That's the essence of cross-validation. Instead of one evaluation, it yields the mean and std of many evaluations. For your example, you are using a 5 split Kfold, which means you will be learning on 4/5 of train data and testing on the remaining 1/5 for 5 times. 
Cross validation is used to be sure that your model is not overfitting.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why is changes in results?

Comment: Your model shows sign of high bias which make me think that it's underfitting. What's the size of your train / test ?

Comment: From where are you inferring that model is underfitting? The sample size is 160. and I use % for validation

Comment: is your data a time serie ? Or has any temporal dependency ? As for the underfitting, it's from the behavior of the model without CV near the end (it diverge far from what it used to predict as if there was not enough information how it should behave for that part of predictions). Also in general for deep learning to really work, we usually need several hundreds / thousands of examples

Comment: I agree with your point that deep learning requires larger data, here I have used only one hidden layer; I feel there is something impacting the variables in memory, because the output should not change with/without presence of some code

Comment: You are not controlling weight initialization nor seeding your train / test partition which also introduce randomness on your results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199575/discussion-between-bhaskar-dhariyal-and-ml-tn).